# android-support-v7-appcompat Não gerar .jar

Tags: android, android-eclipse, app-compat-v7

Estou importando o projeto android-support-v7-appcompat que se encontra em:
*`'../Android/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/'`*

Configuro ele conforme informado na [documentação do Android](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#add-library), apesar de não exibir erro algum acontece que não está gerando os `.jar` dentro da pasta **bin**.

Na verdade não gera nada no **bin**, alguém já teve este tipo de problema?

Estou utilizando o `Eclipse Luna` no `MacOs`.

Comment: Deveria ter gerado, dentro do **BIN** se encontra o  `.jar` do appcompat,   `androidManifest.xml ` e a pasta **RES**,  Você já atribuiu o appcompat ao seu projeto? properties > Android > Library > seleciona o appcompat > OK.

Comment: Isso pode ser problema de compatibilidade com a IDE. Tente utilizar a IDE oficial do Android, o Android Studio: https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui descobrir o erro! 
Toda a arquitetura que estou usando é 64bits e o eclipse era 32!
Com o eclipse certo, tudo funcionou corretamente!

Comment: Não entendi, você estava usando um SDK 64bits e seu eclipse era 32bits isso?

Comment: Exatamente! !!!